# macbook pro: is it better to use a mouse with macbook pro

Tags: mac, macbook, mouse, macbook-pro, touchpad

I want to know is the trackpad really that efficient? say my priority is to get things done Fast, i don't care whether using the trackpad or the mouse is cooler or whatsoever. I'm wondering if there is anyone using mouse on macbook pro?

Side question: if there's a "programming race" going on and you have the choice to use either mouse or trackpad which would you choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely use a mouse! If I were programming on a laptop and using the touchpad, I will rip my hair out! It isn't productive at all. A mouse has much more precision and is much more controllable. But give both a try and see what one you like. I would favor a mouse if I was sitting at a desk.